# Angular xhr request causes redirect warning in Firefox

Tags: firefox, angularjs, angularjs-directive, restangular

Encountered a very annoying "feature" in firefox, related to my angularjs directive.

The directive basically catches a click and then makes a xhr request to the server to update a single value. This all works fine in Chrome & Safari, but in Firefox, every single time you click the button, Firefox throws up a Redirect warning confirmation dialog.

What am I supposed to do in order to *not* have these warnings pop up :(

Comment: Are you just using $http to make the call?

Comment: I'm using Restangular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the backend server was set to automatically append a slash to the url if none was provided in a request. This is done via a redirect.

So for every time the request was made by angular, it resulted in a second redirect, which Firefox picked up and correctly warned about.

On a side note, I'm wondering why this question was Down Voted?